# Search text contains with QueryOver

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I'm trying to do this :

```
var list = Session.QueryOver<Person>()
    .Where(x => x.LastName.Contains(searchText))
    .List<Person>();
```

but I get this error : *Unrecognised method call: System.String:Boolean Contains(System.String)*

Do you have an idea ?

**Update :**

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

NHibernate does not have direct C# equivalent as mentioned on this link http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.html

> Additional Restrictions
>
> Some SQL operators/functions do not have a direct equivalent in C#.
>   (e.g., the SQL where name like '%anna%'). These operators have
>   overloads for QueryOver in the Restrictions class, so you can write:
>
> .Where(Restrictions.On(c => c.Name).IsLike("%anna%"))
>
> There is also an inline syntax to avoid the qualification of the type:
>
> .WhereRestrictionOn(c => c.Name).IsLike("%anna%")

Comment: Thanks, that's work. But NHProf warn me about performance trouble (with 'like'). I'll may be keep my current code, a Nhibernate query and after a linq query on the result.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like QueryOver doesn't support Contains method. You could try with IsLike restriction:

[nhibernate queryover LIKE with expression trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888045/nhibernate-queryover-like-with-expression-trees)
[NHibernate 3.0 search with substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464778/nhibernate-3-0-search-with-substring)
[queryover and (x like 'a' or y like 'a')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541546/queryover-and-x-like-a-or-y-like-a)

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = session.QueryOver<tablename>()    
                  .JoinQueryOver<if another table present>(x => x.Empsals)    
                  .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.FName).IsLike("a%")        
                  .List<EmployeeDetails>();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.FName).IsLike("a%") use like this
```